# "Don't understand what is problem in this code"

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

while loop should go in else statement.but it always become True, when it was 21, its didn't go else statement,

```
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt

hosts_temp="hosts"
hosts_path=r"C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"


redirect="127.0.0.1"
website_list=["www.facebook.com", "facebook.com","www.youtube.com", "youtube.com"]

while True:
    if dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,16) < dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,18):
        print("Working Hours,,,,,,,,.......!!")
        with open(hosts_temp,"r+") as file:
            content=file.read()
            for websites in website_list:
                if websites in content:
                    pass
                else:
                    file.write(redirect+"       "+websites+"\n")
    else:
        with open(hosts_temp,"r+") as file:
            content=file.readlines()
            file.seek(0)
            for line in content:
                if not any(websites in line for websites in website_list):
                    file.write(line)
            file.truncate()
        print("Fun time.......")
    time.sleep(5)
```

I expected it go to the else statement

Comment: Today date (`now()`) at 16 will **always** be lower than Today date (`now()`) at 18. That's why you never go in the else part.

Comment: Did you mean `now().hour < some_value` ?

Comment: but now i mean 9.30 pm it should go to else statement

Comment: i solved this 

if dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,16) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,18):


thank yoou

Answer (score -1):

In python, a while-loop has the following syntax:

```
while (condition):
```

You have your condition set to "true"; therefore, it will always be true.  Do you know what I mean?

Here's the classic example:

```
i = 1
while i < 6:
  print(i)
  i += 1
```

This prints:

```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
```

Because the condition (i < 6) is only true until i becomes 6.